# How to plot data as (X,Y) points with error bars on Y

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I know I need to use ErrorListPlot and a list with elements of the form {{x,y},ErrorBar[e]}. I have x,y,and e all as lists, but I can't figure out how to get a list of of the form...

{ErrorBar[e1],ErrorBar[e2],...,ErrorBar[en]}

... which I'd Riffle together with the list Transpose[{x,y}]. I thought maybe Table[ErrorBar[e[[i]]],{i,1,n}] but I can't use the argument of Part in Table this way.

This should be simple. Maybe I've got some fundamental misunderstanding on plots with error bars?

Comment: Do you have defined a list `e`? If this is the case, there is no issue with doing `Table[ErrorBar[e[[i]]],{i,1,n}]` as long as `n` has a value (here `Length[x]` for instance). You could do as well `e /@ Range[n]`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, and sure enough, it works. I could have sworn I tried it yesterday and it didn't. Must have been some kind of brain cramp.I ended up solving my problem using Map, but I'll go back to the simpler answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define some data

```
x = N[Sqrt[Range[100]]];
y = Sin[2 Pi x / 10];
e = 1/x;
```

Produce the plot

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[MapThread[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} &, {x, y, e}]]
```

[image]